# Python performance issue

Tags: python, web-services

I have the data like below

```
print(json_ls)

[{'user_id': '1', 'lot_number': 'b49d18f1b', 'status': 'send'}, 
 {'user_id': '2', 'lot_number': 'b49d18f1c', 'status': 'send'},
 {'user_id': '3', 'lot_number': 'b49d18f1d', 'status': 'send'},
 {'user_id': '4', 'lot_number': 'b49d18f1e', 'status': 'send'}]
```

And i need to send the above data to API in below format

```
{'users': [

{'user_id': '1',  'status': 'ready'}, 
 {'user_id': '2',  'status': 'ready'},
 {'user_id': '3',  'status': 'ready'},
 {'user_id': '4',  'status': 'ready'}

]}
```

I have written below code, since lot number is needed for url, i have initially consider that in data frame and dropping in below code.

```
final_data = {'users': []}                                              

  for ls in json_ls:
    lot = ls.get("lot_number")
    url = url + lotnumber                                                  
    request_data = {a: b for (a, b) in ls.items() if a != "lot_number"}     
    final_data['users'].append(request_data)

    for users in final_data.get("recipients"):                              
           users["status"] = "ready"
    response = requests.patch(url, data=json.dumps(final_data), headers=headers)
```

To process 500 users to API, it has taken 15 min time and also not all user status as changed to "ready". For each user, the status should be sent with "ready" status.

Could anyone help me on this and also how to improve performance from coding part (i have commented response and checked the execution time. It's faster and seams API itself is taking time to respond for each user)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So the output should just be the userid with a new status? i.e `{'users': [{'user_id': u['user_id'], 'status':'ready'} for u in json_ls]}`?

Comment: The request your sending also looks odd, is it supposed to be within the for loop? every iteration you send the same data with one added entry in it

Comment: Yes @sayse. The status should be updated in each iteration. Because if it fails at middle, remaining users status should be ready only. I agree, it may look odd because i am completely new to it. It would be really helpful if you help me to get better code.

Comment: Without knowing anything about the target api its impossible to answer, I don't see why you'd always have to send across existing data thats already been processed

Comment: I am sending each user data at once so i can get respective lot number that needs to be part of url. I am not processing same user again. I have doubt on for loop that i wrote to change status = 'Ready'. Is it possible to include within the first for loop directly?

Comment: Yes, you are. In your response you send `final_data` and every iteration adds a single `user` to that list, so each request is sending the users that have already been processed, along with 1 extra

Comment: Looks like my code has completely gone wrong. Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your performance issues come down to sending incorrect data, your final data always includes users from previous iterations so you're not updating 500 users, you're updating 1 + 2 + ... + 500 users (125k users)..

Really you don't need final data at all.

```
for ls in json_ls:
    lot = ls.get("lot_number")
    url = url + lotnumber                                                
    response = requests.patch(url, data=json.dumps({'users': [ {'user_id':ls['user_id'], 'status': 'ready'}]}), headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thank you @Sayse. I will check the performance with the above code and mark this response. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Since it is throwing syntax error, i have added close curly bracket to above response. Still it is throwing syntax error. Am i missing something? ```response = requests.patch(url, data=json.dumps({'users': [{ls['user_id'], 'status': 'ready'}]}),headers=headers) ```

Comment: I can't see anything, you'd have to include more information about the error

Comment: ``` SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "<command-2296096190007900>", line 21
    response = requests.patch(url, data=json.dumps({'users': [{ls['user_id'], 'status':'ready'}]}), headers=headers)   
          ^ ```

Comment: The up arrow is showing at colon between status and ready ( 'status':'ready')

Comment: @user11899725 - Ah it thnks its a set, its missing the `'user_id':` for the user id